# How to get in prefect core local task final state?

Tags: python, prefect

I have built a flow which implicitly skips running a given task if a kwarg is empty.

I use something like this within task function for skipping logic:

```
if kwargs.get('processors', Hierarchy()).__len__() == 0:
                    raise signals.SKIP('skipping task',
                                       result=Prediction())
```

I want to build some unit tests to make sure that the final state of said task is skipped. What is the easiest way to get state at a task level?

I can see from docs how to get for a flow but not for a task.

**Update**

To add to Chris's response, I used his 1st proposed option. As my flow is defined outside of the tests I created a simple function to get a set of tasks that had skipped. In the test this was compared against a list of tasks that should have skipped:

```
def get_skipped_tasks(flow_state):
        return set(key.name for key, value in flow_state.result.items() if value.is_skipped())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways that I'll include here for completeness; for my example I'll use this basic flow:

```py
from prefect import task, Flow
from prefect.engine.signals import SKIP
import random


@task
def random_number():
    return random.randint(0, 100)

@task
def is_even(num):
    if num % 2:
        raise SKIP("odd number")
    return True

with Flow("dummy") as flow:
    even_task = is_even(random_number)
```

### Run the whole flow

When running interactively you can always run the whole flow and access individual task states from the parent flow run state; note that when you "call" a task (e.g., `is_even(random_number)`) a copy is created, so you need to track these copies correctly.

```py
flow_state = flow.run()

assert flow_state.result[even_task].is_skipped() # for example
```

### Run a piece of the flow with mocked data

When running interactively you can also pass a dictionary of task -> state that the runner will respect; these states can optionally be provided data:

```py
from prefect.engine.state import Success

mocked_state = Success(result=2)


flow_state = flow.run(task_states={random_number: mocked_state})
assert not flow_state.result[even_task].is_skipped()
```

### Use a TaskRunner

Lastly, if you want to run state-based tests on this task alone you can use a `TaskRunner`.  This gets a *little* more complicated because you have to recreate the upstream dependencies using `Edge`s.

```py
from prefect.engine.task_runner import TaskRunner
from prefect.edge import Edge

runner = TaskRunner(task=even_task)
edge = Edge(key="num", upstream_task=random_number, downstream_task=even_task)


task_state = runner.run(upstream_states={edge: mocked_state})
assert not task_state.is_skipped()
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks for your quick response!